# How to make datastructure of venn diagram in d3 js javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, underscore.js

I have this array data

```
var array = [
    {"package": "20Dresses - Shop Women Fashion", "total": 4857},
    {"total": 24, "competingapps": "com.stylecracker.android"},
    {"total": 578, "competingapps": "com.shopping.limeroad"},
    {"total": 291, "competingapps": "com.craftsvilla.app"},
    {"total": 430, "competingapps": "com.voonik.android"}
];
```

From this array data i have to make this following data structure for venn diagram.

```
var vennSets = [
     {"sets": [0], "label": "20Dresses - Shop Women Fashion", "size": 4857},
     {"sets": [1], "label": "com.stylecracker.android", "size": 24},
     {"sets": [2], "label": "com.shopping.limeroad", "size": 578},
     {"sets": [3], "label": "com.craftsvilla.app", "size": 291},
     {"sets": [4], "label": "com.voonik.android", "size": 430},
     {"sets": [0, 1], "size": 24},
     {"sets": [0, 2], "size": 578},
     {"sets": [0, 3], "size": 291},
     {"sets": [0, 4], "size": 430},
]
```

I dont understand how can i achieve the above strucutre. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it only needs some basic transformations

```
// considering array is your initial array;
var singleItems = [];
var intersections = [];
var vennSets;

array.forEach(function(item, index) {
  singleItems.push({
    sets: [index],
    label: item.package || item.competingapps,
    size: item.total
  });

  if (item.competingapps) {
    intersections.push({
      sets: [0, index],
      size: item.total
    });
  }
});

vennSets = singleItems.concat(intersections);
```

You might like to stick with more functional way of transformations to avoid outer scope pollution with temporary variables (`singleItems` and `intersections`);

```
var result = array.reduce(function(prev, item, index) {
  prev.push({
    sets: [index],
    label: item.package || item.competingapps,
    size: item.total
  });

  if (item.competingapps) {
    prev.push({
      sets: [0, index],
      size: item.total
    });
  }

  return prev;
}, []).sort(function(a, b) { return a.sets.length < b.sets.length; });
```